# All Plotly Plot_geo segments add segment to lat/long of 0,0

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am making some maps on plotly with the flight paths/lines and i recently updated such things as the java version i was utilizing and i got the following map...as you can tell it is in correct. Every point is connecting to a second point somewhere in the atlantic (0,0). Plotly version 4.5.6 and 4.5.2.

```
library(plotly)

lat1 <- runif(10, 40,50)
lat2 <- runif(10, 40,50)
long1 <- runif(10, 40,50)
long2 <- runif(10, 40,50)

df <- data.frame(lat1, lat2, long1, long2)

plot_geo(locationmode = 'USA-states')  %>%
  add_markers(data = df, x = ~long1, y = ~lat1, color = I("red")) %>% 
  add_markers(data = df, x = ~long2, y = ~lat2, color = I("blue")) %>% 
  add_segments(
    data = df,name = "Paths",
    x = ~long1, xend = ~long2,
    y = ~lat1, yend = ~lat2,
    alpha = 0.3, size = I(3), hoverinfo = 'none'
  )
```

This gives the following graph...with all segments being connected to each other and to a lat/long of 0,0.  Can anyone help me figure out why?

[image]

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of your problems, but it would have been much easier to do this: `df <- data.frame(lat1, lat2, long1, long2)`. Try to avoid using cbind if you can avoid it when creating dataframes.

Comment: not the source, sorry for the poor code.  I was typing it quickly for an example and didn't code check, I'll make the changes (same result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split your segments with `split`. You can use an id on each line like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id=1:10,lat1, lat2, long1, long2)

plot_geo(locationmode = 'USA-states')  %>%
  add_markers(data = df, x = ~long1, y = ~lat1, color = I("red")) %>% 
  add_markers(data = df, x = ~long2, y = ~lat2, color = I("blue")) %>% 
  add_segments(
    data = df,name = "Paths",
    x = ~long1, xend = ~long2,
    y = ~lat1, yend = ~lat2, split=~id,
    alpha = 0.3, size = I(3), hoverinfo = 'none'
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed.  Is there a way to group all of those segments in the legend? When you look at the legend you will see all of the id's as separate lines, and i cannot get `grouplegend` to work for all of them, any thoughts?

Comment: Please post a new question with reproducible code and expected results